# How to preserve window state when using keybindings

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings

I'm currently working on a game that's based on a client-server architecture. What basically happens is that one player can create a lobby that others can connect to by providing IP address and port number (so, actually basic Java Sockets). Before the actual game is started, all players are first placed inside a lobby which consists of a JLabel displaying the player count and a JTextArea providing information about people joining or leaving the lobby. Everytime a new player connects or someone leaves the lobby, the host pushes out notifications to the clients for updating their UI correspondingly.

The problem is now the following: I want the lobby to be displayable in fullscreen if the user likes (which is also implemented already using keybindings/Input-/Actionmaps). However, when a user changes from window to fullscreen or back the current frame has to be disposed and as a consequence reset to the initial lobby state. I originally wanted to solve this using the class `LobbyState` which stores all relevant data to be restored. However, somehow this is not working as the frame still displays the initial state of the lobby when changing "window-mode".

To give you an insight into the code, this is the relevant code of the `Lobby` class:

```
private int playerCount = 1;
private boolean isHost;

public Lobby(Integer windowState, Image image, Boolean isHost, LobbyState lobbyState) {

    this.isHost = isHost;
    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Lobby");
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setSize(screenDim);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

    setIconImage(image);
    
    if (windowState == 1) {
        setUndecorated(true);
    } else {
        setUndecorated(false);
    }
    setResizable(true);

    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setLayout(null);
    contentPane.getInputMap(KeyBindings.AFC).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F11"), "lobby_fullscreen");
    contentPane.getActionMap().put("lobby_fullscreen", new EnterFullscreen(this, this.isHost, new LobbyState(playerCount, getLobbyHistory())));
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(253, 205, 136));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    loadComponents();
    loadBounds();
    addActionListeners();

    if (lobbyState != null) {
        lblPlayerCount.setText("" + lobbyState.getPlayerCount());
        txtLobbyHistory.setText(lobbyState.getLobbyHistory());
    }
    
    setVisible(true);

}
```

My first assumption why `F11` triggers the creation of a Lobby with the initial state instead of the current state is, that the `ActionMap` is created when `playerCount` is still 1 and `getLobbyHistory()` doesn't return anything because there actually still is no lobby history. If this is really the problem, is there any possibility to tell the ActionMap to re-read the values of `playerCount` and `getLobbyHistory()` whenever `F11` is pressed? Would I have to remove the current ActionMap and add a new one or is there a more elegant way to solve this?

In case this is of any interest, this is the code that currently performs the toggle between window and fullscreen application:

```
public class EnterFullscreen extends AbstractAction{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1773898497666165938L;
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean isHost;
    private LobbyState lobbyState;
    private Class<?> frameType;
    private Constructor<?> c;
    
    public EnterFullscreen(JFrame frame, boolean isHost, LobbyState lobbyState) {
        
        this.frame = frame;
        this.isHost = isHost;
        this.lobbyState = lobbyState;
        
        try {
            frameType = frame.getClass();
            if (frameType.equals(Lobby.class)) {
                c = frameType.getConstructor(Integer.class, Image.class, Boolean.class, LobbyState.class);  
            } else {
                c = frameType.getConstructor(Integer.class, Image.class, Boolean.class);    
            }
        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        try {
            
            frame.setVisible(false);
            if (frame.isUndecorated()) {
                if (frameType.equals(Lobby.class)) {
                    c.newInstance(0, frame.getIconImage(), isHost, lobbyState);
                } else {
                    c.newInstance(0, frame.getIconImage(), isHost);
                }
            } else {
                if (frameType.equals(Lobby.class)) {
                    c.newInstance(1, frame.getIconImage(), isHost, lobbyState);
                } else {
                    c.newInstance(1, frame.getIconImage(), isHost);
                }
            }

            frame.dispose();
            
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I'd really appreciate any input on how to solve this and how one would achieve something like this properly. If you feel like there's any missing information or code to solve this, please let me know and I'll try to provide that as soon as possible.

Comment: Step back for a second - you're on he right track.  You're UI should be getting information from a model and monitoring state changes via some kind of observer/delegate, then it won't matter which UI you have present.  I am, kind of worried, about the use of `getConstructor` ... but who am I to judge.  One concept you might want to look into is the "model-view-controller" concept.  You'll also want to be familiar with the "observer pattern"

Comment: `c.newInstance` isn't been assigned to anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess the `c.newInstance` actually works, I don't know what you mean with that it isn't assigned to anything? Because for me it creates a new instance of the lobby (or the other window). But I'm also not really sure what you mean with "the UI should be getting information from a model"? Does this have to do with the "model-view-controller" concept you wrote about in the end or is this something that I already should have implemented? Also, are there any issues that can arise with the use of `getConstructor` because this code was suggested in a different SO article?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, I just took a look into the first lines of what a model-view-controller looks like and I think I get that point. I guess a possible solution would therefore be to store the relevant data still e.g. in `LobbyState` but no longer store the data in `Lobby` and get updates only from `LobbyState`, right? I'll take a look into the observer pattern next but already thanks for that input.

Comment: So, what you might want to do, is start by creating a single instance of your model.  Create a single UI based on something like a `JPanel` to display the information from the model.  This should also register itself to the model so it can notified of changes and make updates to the UI (this is the observer part).  When needed, create and configure the window you want to use and simply add the same instance of the panel to it - this will allow you to "move" the panel from one window to another without needing a lot more configuration/setup.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for that explanation. I guess I did something similar just without the additional `JPanel`. Now, I have a model running in the background receiving all the updates and pushing them to the `JFrame`. And whenever a new `JFrame` is created, the `JFrame` updates the reference to itself in the model and requests the current state from the model. Although this includes some extra steps in comparison to your solution with the `JPanel` I guess it makes little sense to rewrite all the code for such a solution, right?

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid having the `JFrame` as your top level control - lots of replication going.  Using a `JPanel` as you start point means you only need one and then it becomes a self contained unit of work.  All you then need to do is move the panel from one frame to another, which should simply the logic a lot